# Consolidate files into one sheet with filenames issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a small problem when combining all of my files into one sheet. For some reason, Only the first sheet with the filename at the top gets copied over correctly, on every other copied over section it's missing the first line where I have inserted the filename.

I'm wondering if it has to do with the way I have inserted the filename but

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
'PLACES ALL FILES IN FOLDER INTO ONE COMBINED FILE
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
[A1].Formula = "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"
[A1].Cells(1).Select
[A1].Cells.Copy
[A1].Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
[A1].Cells(1).Select
Sheet.Copy Before:=wbk.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges:=False
Filename = Dir()
Loop


'COMBINES WORKSHEETS INTO ONE COMBINED WORKSHEET
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined Totals"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(2)

Next
```

Comment: In your `Sheet` loop you are only ever referring to the active sheet, not the sheet in question.

Comment: Why Offset on this line Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select ? Sheet 2 has separate copy for row 1 before entering the For J = 2 To Sheets.Count loop so for that sheet the offset does not matter.